# Can I return an anonymous object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

My code returns an object:

```
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAnswers(int userTestQuestionId)
    {

  return Ok(new AnswerToClientDTO
        {
            AnswerGridCorrect = answerGridCorrect,
            Result = result,
            UpdateRowCount = updateRowCount
        });
```

Here is the code for the AnswerToClientDTO which is only used in the one place in my application:

```
public class AnswerToClientDTO
{
    public string AnswerGridCorrect { get; set; }
    public int UpdateRowCount { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible for me to return an anonymous object where I do not have to declare a class from an ASP.NET WEb API method?

Comment: yes if you change your return type to object or dynamic.

Comment: You can simply try it )

Comment: You can return `dynamic` but I wouldn't recommend it... type safety is a good thing. Wouldn't it be nice if your code didn't compile if you introduced a breaking change?

Comment: How should I construct the object if I don't have something to new ?

Comment: @Alan But you *do* have an object to create.

Comment: The answer is that you can certainly do it, but it is nearly useless, because any static type information available to the compiler becomes lost.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It depends on the specifics of the method though.  For example, if the object is just going to be serialized, or data bound, and not accessed statically (which seems like it might actually be the case here) then returning an `object` would be fine.  It is an unusual and exceptional case though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In WebAPI you can pass any object to `Ok()`, which can be formatted by a configured formatter, so this should be valid:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetStuff()
{
    return Ok( new {
        AnswerGridCorrect = answerGridCorrect,
        Result = result,
        UpdateRowCount = updateRowCount
    } );
}
```

Comment: How should we read/get this value in another method of c# ?

Comment: @ManirajSS you shouldn't do this, because public actions are only for external use (e.g. via HTTP pipe-line) If you have to shere some data between couple of API actions you should create private method which returns common data in some DTO or ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes you can provided you use `object` or `dynamic`. That being said it is not a good idea.  Also, if you are using this for a WebAPI like you mentioned (such as a REST or SOAP service via WCF) this would be a bad idea since the serialization from the HTTP call / to response won't know the proper formatting to use to send data back as JSON or XML.

Comment: Mr/Ms Downvoter care to explain the problem in my answer?